# 同じ階層のViewサイズを知る方法について

Tags: android

お世話になっております。
現在AndroidでCustomViewを実装しているのですが、なかなか解決できない所があり
質問させて頂きました。

ViewGroupの同一階層にViewを2つaddViewしました。(ViewAとViewBとします)
ViewA.height == ViewB.heightもしくはViewA.width == ViewB.width
と状況によりViewBのheightもしくはwidthをViewAと合わせたいと考えています。
このViewAとViewBを重ね合わせて表示します。
状況によりこのViewAの幅もしくは高さにViewBの幅もしくは高さを合わせたいと考えています。

そこで質問なのですが、
ViewBからViewAのサイズや位置を取得する方法はありませんでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RelativeLayout`で次のようにleftとrightを合わせるようにするといけます。

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <MyViewA
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
    <MyViewB
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/view1"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: ちなみに、カスタムViewGroupで、子供Viewの大きさを知るには`onMeasure()`内で確か計算できます。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
教えて頂いた方法試してみます。
CustomViewGroupを作るとonMeasureで子Viewの大きさを知れるのは
初耳でした。試してみます。